# What is the alternative of @api.one in Odoo 13?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

Right now when I started coding on Odoo v13 I found that Odoo has been removed `@api.one`.

What is the alternative of the `@api.one` in Odoo v13 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `odoo13` by default instance method will accept `self` as `multi` instance (multi-recordset).

So for instance method, you should remove the `@api.one` and `@api.multi` decorator from your methods.

For a single instance(single recordset), you still can check with `self.ensure_one()` or you can apply your own logic.